Best way to handle multiple URLLoader Requests in AS3
I have written the following class to abstract multiple calls to my server for sending data to a database and getting that data back.
package {
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLVariables;
import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
import flash.net.URLLoaderDataFormat;


public class sqlReq extends URLLoader {

    private var phpVars: URLVariables;
    private var phpFileRequest: URLRequest;
    private var phpLoader: URLLoader;
    private var tempPhpVars: String;
    private var totalBytes: uint;
    
    public function sqlReq(link: String, dataVars: String) {
        // constructor code

        phpVars = new URLVariables();
        phpFileRequest = new URLRequest(link);
        phpFileRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
        phpLoader = new URLLoader();


        phpLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
        phpLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, phpReqCompleted);
        phpLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, phpReqError);
        phpLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.NETWORK_ERROR, phpReqNetworkError);
        phpLoader.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, phpReqprogress);
        //phpLoader.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, phpReqErrorhttpStatus);


        phpFileRequest.data = dataVars;
        phpLoader.load(phpFileRequest);
    }


    private function phpReqCompleted(event: Event): void {

        //trace("returned vars",event.target.data);
        tempPhpVars = event.target.data;
        this.dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE));
        clearEvents();

    }

    private function phpReqError(event: IOErrorEvent): void {
        this.dispatchEvent(new IOErrorEvent(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR));

        tempPhpVars = "resultIs:" + event.target.data;
        //trace("Code Confirmed: " + event);

    }
    public function phpReqResults(): String {
        return tempPhpVars;
    }
    public function ByteAmount(): uint {
    
        return totalBytes;
        
    }
    private function phpReqprogress(event: ProgressEvent): void {
        //trace(event.bytesLoaded, "total ", event.bytesTotal);
        totalBytes = event.bytesTotal;
        this.dispatchEvent(new ProgressEvent(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS));

    }
    private function phpReqNetworkError(event: IOErrorEvent): void {
        this.dispatchEvent(new IOErrorEvent(IOErrorEvent.NETWORK_ERROR));
        //phpVars = event.target.data;
        //trace("Code Confirmed: " + event);
    }
    private function clearEvents(): void {
        phpLoader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, phpReqCompleted);
        phpLoader.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, phpReqError);
        phpLoader.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.NETWORK_ERROR, phpReqNetworkError);
        phpLoader.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, phpReqprogress);
        //phpLoader.removeEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, phpReqErrorhttpStatus);
        phpVars = null;
        phpLoader = null;
        phpFileRequest = null;

    }
}
    }

The code has been working flawlessly, until recently, I noticed something strange. For example, when I make multiple requests back to back, the second sql request gets the data of the previous sql request. If I create timer and wait, everything is fine, but I do need to be able to send multiple requests and I should expect different results for the different requests.
And these are the calls I make in the app (I do import all necessary classes so the code runs fine). The main issue: once in a while (more often than not), getName would return null and getAge would work, other times, getAge would return null and getName would work. If I call these functions separately, they ALWAYS work. Is there anything I am missing.
    var sql:sqlReq;

    var myTimer: Timer = new Timer(500, 20);

    myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTick);
    myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, onTimeUp);

    function getName():void{
        sql= new sqlReq("http://mysite.php","&user=Sarah");
        sql.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,gotMyName);
        sql.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,ErrorGettingMyName);
    }
    function getAge():void{
        sql= new sqlReq("http://mysite.php","&age=32");
        sql.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,gotMyAge);
        sql.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,ErrorGettingMyAge);
    }
    function gotMyName(event:Event):void{
       //All good
    }
     function gotMyAge(event:Event):void{
       //All good
    }
    function ErrorGettingMyName(event:IOErrorEvent):void{
       //All bad
    }
    function ErrorGettingMyAge(event:IOErrorEvent):void{
       //All bad
    }

    function onTick(event:TimerEvent):void{
    
        getName();
        getAge();
    }
    function onTimeUp(event:TimerEvent):void{
         //clear and remove timer events
    }


You uer this and phpLoader inconsistently. IMHO you either need to employ this as the core instance that does and handles the request, or instantiate a URLLoader with correct GET/POST data and listen to that. Also why dispatching events in event handlers? Also the problem might be in how do you use this class - you need a separate instance per request, the class looks like it's not safe to reuse in any case, so you create, send, receive data and dispose the object instead of doing fancy stuff.

I don't see any problems with the class, but I see the problem here: var sql:sqlReq; If you want to run many requests simultaneously, you need to keep EVERY instance of sqlReq (e.g. in Array), otherwise garbage collector might remove the ones without references to them. Also, when handling events from your class, use event.target to figure from which instance you are supposed to get the data from.

Thank you both Vesper and @Organis for these helpful comments. So, if I understood correctly, I should be doing sqlA,sqlB, etc. instead of resuing the same one, correct? And, clean up the 'this' in the class. For dispatching the events from the class, are you saying they are redundant and not needed? How would I know in my app in the event was completed? The way it works, I check if the event is completed, and if so, other code needs to run.

If you have function arguments with the same names as class fields, this explicitly tells to use the field over the argument. This is not your case, so you as well might omit it. I'll add another part as an answer.

If I were to devise such a system, I'd do the following (there might be some errors in the code since I stopped doing AS3 some 7 years ago, but the logic of how it supposed to be should be solid so I believe in you figuring it all out):
First, I wouldn't put the network request itself into the constructor, but rather into a separate method. Why? Flash is asynchronous, you never know WHEN the events fire, better safe than sorry:
        phpLoader.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, phpReqprogress);
        //phpLoader.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, phpReqErrorhttpStatus);
    }

    public function request(): void
    {
        phpFileRequest.data = dataVars;
        phpLoader.load(phpFileRequest);
    }

Then, the Array to keep the requests while they are running:
var SQLs: Array = new Array;

function isActive(sql: sqlReq): Boolean
{
    var index: int = SQLs.indexOf(sql);
    
    return index > -1;
}

// Single gate to delete the sqlReq instance.
function removeRequest(sql: sqlReq, completeHandler: Function, errorHandler: Function): void
{
    var index: int = SQLs.indexOf(sql);
    
    if (index < 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    
    SQLs.splice(index, 1);
    
    // Unsubscribe from events.
    sql.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
    sql.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, errorHandler);
}

So, when you create new requests, you do as following:
function getName(): void
{
    var sql: sqlReq = new sqlReq("http://mysite.php","&user=Sarah");
    
    // Store the instance.
    SQLs.push(sql);
    
    // Subscribe for the events.
    sql.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, gotMyName);
    sql.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ErrorGettingMyName);
    
    // Run the request.
    sql.request();
}

Then, in (all) the handlers you need to do:
function gotMyName(event: Event): void
{
    // Get reference to the author of the event.
    var sql: sqlReq = event.target as sqlReq;
    
    // Check if it is an active request and not some rogue.
    if (!isActive(sql))
    {
        // Do not process the request if you cannot identify it.
        return;
    }

    // All good.
    // ...
    // Your code here.
    
    // Put the request to the rest.
    removeRequest(sql, gotMyName, ErrorGettingMyName);
}


Thank you so much for your time- I like your logic, but I will test and report back. I will also adjust the class in light of your note about events firing. Thank you a lot

@FlashV8 I edited the post as I realized that removeEventListener needs 2 arguments. Good luck getting it to work.

Worked liked a charm. THANK YOU!!!!

@FlashV8 Oh, great. I am glad to still remember something : )))

really, it worked PERFECTLY! I could not be more grateful. Thank you so much. Maybe you should come back and start coding again in Adobe Air? I even noticed less lag between requests results. :) Happy Holidays!

@FlashV8 I've been with Flash/AS1/2/3 from 2001 to 2017. I've seen it rise to its glory in 2008-2009 then fall to oblivion. Adobe had lost it all: the battle for the web and the battle for the mobile likewise. Even Ruffle is not able to truly resurrect Flash, just to animate its dead remains. I just moved on. Well, maybe, when I retire, I'll unearth my Flash tools once again and start creating some stupid games, who knows?

That's pretty impressive, you have been with the platform for that long. I sadly agree that it is not now what it used to be, but I still use it a lot and I love it. Mainly creating apps for desktop to use in my classes to engage my students- so far, I haven't hit any limitation in my use cases, which is why I still use it. Thanks for sharing. Have a great holiday and best wishes for a great new year!
